# Twilsock connection closed by server error show after uploaded to server

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, twilio

I'm getting these errors after my project is run on server. In my local machine it's well done.

**Twilsock connection closed by server**

Here is my code in token.php

```
 <?php 
require_once('./twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php');
 require_once('./config.php');

 $appName => 'TwilioChatDemo';

 $identity = $_GET['identity'];

 $deviceId = $_GET['device'];

 $endpointId => $appName . ':' . $identity . ':' . $deviceId;

 $token = new Services_Twilio_AccessToken(
     $TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, 
     $TWILIO_API_KEY, 
     $TWILIO_API_SECRET, 
     3600, 
     $identity ); 
      $ipmGrant = new Services_Twilio_Auth_IpMessagingGrant();
 $ipmGrant->setServiceSid($TWILIO_IPM_SERVICE_SID);
 $ipmGrant->setEndpointId($endpointId);

 $token->addGrant($ipmGrant); 
 json_encode(array(
     'identity' => $identity,
     'token' => $token->toJWT(), ));
```

Here is index.js

```
$.getJSON('/token.php', { 
        identity: mainuser,
        device: 'browser'
    }, function(data) {

        username = data.identity;
        print('You have been logged in as: ' 
            + '<span class="me">' + username + '</span>', true);

        accessManager = new Twilio.AccessManager(data.token);
        messagingClient = new Twilio.IPMessaging.Client(accessManager);
```

so , what's wrong with me.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328494/twilio-twilsock-connection-closed-by-server

Comment: Response not same. My issue is response (401 - unauthorized) to https://cds.twilio.com/v2/Streams.